# Display dynamic list of Oxyplot charts in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, oxyplot

When displaying a chart using oxyplot in a wpf application:

```
<oxy:PlotView Title="My Chart" Model="{Binding SomePlotModel}"></oxy:PlotView>
```

Will display the chart.

But if you want to display multiple charts in a ListBox

```
<ListBox >
    <ListBoxItem>
        <oxy:PlotView Title="My Chart1" Model="{Binding SomePlotModel1}"></oxy:PlotView>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <oxy:PlotView Title="My Chart2" Model="{Binding SomePlotModel2}"></oxy:PlotView>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

The charts will not display. Why? How do you display a dynamic list of charts using Oxyplot?

Answer (score 0):

Width and Height! Oxyplot line 583 of PlotBase

```
((IPlotModel)this.ActualModel).Render(this.renderContext, this.canvas.ActualWidth, this.canvas.ActualHeight);
```

If you dump a plot in a ListBox the width and height of the canvas for the plot are zero unless set. 
This works in my example :

```
<ListBox >
<ListBoxItem>
    <oxy:PlotView Title="My Chart1" Model="{Binding SomePlotModel1}"  Width="200" Height="200"></oxy:PlotView>
</ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem>
    <oxy:PlotView Title="My Chart2" Model="{Binding SomePlotModel2}"  Width="200" Height="200"></oxy:PlotView>
</ListBoxItem>
```